# WCF Service Connection Issues - Only Two Computers Can Connect

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

So in my office, there's a WCF service running on a computer with Windows 7 - this WCF service is, for all intents and purposes, within a black box. (I could dig into it, but that could affect the 3rd party software we use to interface with the machine it's attached to, and I do not want to do that.)

As the title indicates, only two computers can connect to the WCF service - my development environment, and the service computer itself (connecting to localhost, so not very surprising that it can connect). The connection is made through a VB.NET application by http to a .svc web page. The application is being developed in Visual Studio. The connection was added by adding a Web Service Reference to the url. The application is regularly built for release and distributed to the various computers that need to run it.

However, another developer with the same OS as myself (Windows 10) can't connect to the WCF service.

All the computers that should be able to connect to the WCF ARE able to navigate to the services' url, and are able to ping to the computer.

I've tried multiple different urlacl configurations, all of which result in the same thing: only my computer and the localhost can connect.

If anyone has any idea of how to resolve this issue, I'm all ears, as this is utterly baffling to me.

Edit: Here's some information from the SVC log:

The HTTP service located at http://sam/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/e823c303-06c5-4843-a6dd-acb47be15dc1/dc9f817a-9781-4ba9-87a6-bc83a2cb4b81 is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.

This occurred at the same time that the application attempted to connect to the service.

Comment: You need to provide the exact symptoms (error messages, codes, etc.) for us to be able to help you. You can probably troubleshoot this yourself, though, by enabling WCF tracing on both sides and inspect the resulting logs.

Comment: I've done that, and literally everything that it gives me is just a timeout error. It refuses to spit anything else out, it's infuriating.

Comment: That suggests a general connectivity issue.

Comment: Quick update - I've looked into it and the logs haven't been being spit out, at all - I've been getting nothing because it's been giving nothing. I think I may have set up my trace incorrectly, I'll troubleshoot that first then get back to you.

Comment: Here's the errors:The HTTP service located at http://sam/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/e823c303-06c5-4843-a6dd-acb47be15dc1/dc9f817a-9781-4ba9-87a6-bc83a2cb4b81 is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.

Comment: Is "sam" an entry in the hosts file? I.e. if the computers ping sam, do they all ping the same IP address?

Comment: Yes, the SAM is actually the computer that hosts the service. There's the same error messages for other computers as well - it will say their computer name, along with indicating that there was an "incorrect address or SOAP action".

Comment: there is no port specified in the config file for the client, and if I do it breaks on my dev computer.

Comment: try calling the service using an IP address maybe instead of the pc name?

Comment: I've tried that, still doesn't work...I've also now tried adding multiple endpoints, and it informs me that there is "nothing listening" at the endpoint.

Comment: You might to create a little console test application where you create the service from code instead of a service reference and see different URL's

Comment: how does the client invoke the service? when the client calls WCF via adding service reference, the default endpoint address generated by the client is LOCALHOST. please check the client endpoint configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - it was a firewall issue. The WCF service was attempting to patch into port 80 as a listening address. I added an inbound rule for TCP Port 80 on the computers we want to connect to the service.